# SqlCeResultSet.Close - Do I need to call it?

Tags: .net

I have seen some examples that after data is read using SqlCeResultSet that a Close is called.

Do I really need to call close?  What are the drawbacks if I don't close it?  (does something else bad happen?  Do I get memory leaks?....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to `Close` your result sets; otherwise, you may leak native resources.

You should simply use a `using` block.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Alas a using block will not work.  I have a multi function use of the result set (ie one method to setup a table, another to do all my inserts updates and deletes on a table.)  I will just close before I setup my table.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The drawback if you don't close the result set yourself is that the resources won't be freed until the garbage collector gets around to it. A lot of garbage collectors are lazy, so who knows when that will be!